# Dynamic Value in variable php

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I have a Variable with a dinamic value inside.

My problem is, I can't patch this Variable anywhere when I change to another PHP file.
I tried to register this Variable in a XML file, into the mysql data base, with constants, and nothing works, the value of my Variable will always reset.

Is there a way for me to freeze that variable value and use it later?

Thanks in advance.

PS: i looked for weeks in here and other places. Because im human I might have failed to realise hiden anwsers. If for some reason this is a duplicate please indicate the post, im very tired by now I might not be thinking strait.

EDIT:

The code is:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

I recieve page1.php?id=51

Then I use $id = $_GET['id'];

To get the ID value (51)

And this is the value I would like to "freeze" to use in page2.php because if I navigate to page2.php the $id is gone.

Comment: Can you supply some code to show what you mean. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "patch this variable when changing to another file" in this context?

Comment: persistent variable options: a file, a database; if its persistent to one user : session\coockie. if you need help with your chosen method, you need to show us the code used, and explain the issues you had with the code

Comment: You should store the `$_GET['id']` into a session variable. Once you get to page 2 you can just retrieve the value.

Comment: What the hell! It did work LOL Why Havent I tried this before. Thank you uom-pgregorio

Comment: We'll blame it to the holidays. I myself can't wait to leave the office and my brain isn't working at full capacity. Let's just leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session :)

> page 1

```
<?php
ob_start(); session_start();
?>
<?php

echo "<a href='page_1.php?id=51'>page_1.php?id=51</a>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href='page_2.php'>page_2</a>";
echo "<br /><br />";

if(!empty($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $_SESSION['page_id'] = $id;
}

if(!empty($id))
{
   echo $id;
}

?>
```

> page 2

```
<?php
ob_start(); session_start();
?>
<?php

echo "<a href='page_1.php?id=51'>page_1.php?id=51</a>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href='page_2.php'>page_2</a>";
echo "<br /><br />";

if(!empty($_SESSION['page_id']))
{
   $id = $_SESSION['page_id'];
}

if(!empty($id))
{
   echo $id;
}

?>
```